# How to search by label across the boards, and across the teams in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I just started using Trello. I want to add labels and then use them later to filter from a multitude of cards, across all my boards.

How can this be achieved?

I've used the normal search functionality form all boards panel - but it's only searching card name, card description and board name. Not labels. I tested it.

I think searching by label across all boards is a very desirable feature.

Any ideas how to do this now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter is only applied for cards on that specific board, however if you have the same label applied across different boards you can use the search feature along with our search operator "label:" to search for cards across all boards with that label.

You can read more about all the search operators available here:

http://help.trello.com/article/808-searching-for-cards-all-boards